# Segmentation fault when entering a file as an argument [C Language]

Tags: c

I'm using a simple reading in my program using fgets and some break conditions, and for some reason when I compile and run the program with
./program < input.txt
it presents a Seg Fault.

But when I run the program with 
./program
and paste the same content that the input file has, it runs normally.

This is the code I'am using:

```
void readInput()
{
    char lote[20], str[505];
    char *msg;
    int par, ord, k;
    scanf("%d", &k);

    while(1)
    {
        __fpurge(stdin);
        fgets(lote, 20, stdin);
        if (strcmp(lote, "-1\n") == 0)
            break;
        while(1)
        {
            __fpurge(stdin);
            fgets(str, 505, stdin);
            if(strcmp(str, "Fim\n") == 0)
                break;
            par = atoi(strtok(str, ";"));
            ord = atoi(strtok(NULL, ";"));
            msg = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            printf("Par = %d/Ordem = %d/Mensagem=%s\n", par, ord, msg);                 

        }
    }
}
```

Edit: This is the input file:

```
10
Lote 1
3;2;Estou fazendo agora
0;1;Olá, tudo bem com você?
1;2;Não
1;1;Você vem jantar hoje?
0;2;Tudo sim e você?
1;3;Vou ter que trabalhar até mais tarde
2;4;se você lembrar
3;1;Conseguiu fazer o TP?
3;3;Esta muito fácil
Fim
Lote 2
2;2;Vou
2;3;leva na aula amanha
0;3;Tudo bem tbm
4;2;Parabéns! Que dia vamos comemorar?
2;1;Vai precisar da grana?
4;1;Passei no vestibular!
3;4;Esta mesmo
Fim
-1
```

Comment: WTF is `__fpurge()`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen A non-standard function that supports flushing `stdin`.

Comment: Use sscanf instead of atoi

Comment: @cpp_prog just **no** -- maybe use `strtol()` for better diagnostics.

Comment: why not @FelixPalmen? after all, sscanf returns whether there was an error or not

Comment: @cpp_prog because it's all *bells and whistles* where you really don't need them.

Comment: @FelixPalmen `strtol` is harder to use than sscanf.

Comment: @cpp_prog no it isn't.

Comment: @FelixPalmen strtol requires endpointer. Compare `char *endptr; val = strtol(str, &endptr, base);` to `sscanf(str, "%d", &val);`

Comment: @cpp_prog The sscanf command enters in an endless loop for the first line input, so it doesn't fit in this problem.

Comment: @cpp_prog the `scanf()` family of functions is among the *hardest to use* functions in standard C, just look at all these questions around it. And if all you want to do is parse a single integer, it's like trying to use a mainframe for computing `1+1`. Really, there's a reason functions like `atoi()` and `strtol()` exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `__fpurge` is the culprit here.  It's flushing the entire input buffer.  The reason it's working by pasting the lines into the console is that only one line at a time is read, while using an input redirection feeds the whole thing in at once.

After the `scanf`, do a single call to `getchar` to absorb the newline that's left in the buffer.  Then get rid of the `__fpurge` calls, and it should work.

Comment: that's what I found debugging this thing (+1) ... (without `__fpurge()`). I'd advise against the `scanf()` family of functions, I get the impression around 50% of beginners' questions here deal with problems related to `scanf()`... btw, will a single `getchar()` work on windows? ... better just use `fgets()` and parse yourself.

Comment: @dbush So, I've tried what you said, and it runs perfectly on a manual input, but when I do the ./program < input.txt it shows the Seg Fault again =/

Comment: @Barretxx are you on windows? Just read your first line with `fgets()`, too. And if you need the value of `k`, use `atoi()` here, too.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I'm using Linux Mint. I've already tried to read the k variable with fgets and use the atoi later too, but Seg Fault disturbed me once again.

Comment: @Barretxx I just added an answer demonstrating this little change. Still I think **this** answer here hits the nail

Answer (score 0):

I think @dbush already explained the problem quite well, but just for completeness, here's some perfectly working code with just a minor variation of the original:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char lote[20], str[505];
    char *msg;
    int par, ord, k;
    fgets(lote, 20, stdin);
    k = atoi(lote);

    while(1)
    {
        fgets(lote, 20, stdin);
        if (strcmp(lote, "-1\n") == 0)
            break;
        while(1)
        {
            fgets(str, 505, stdin);
            if(strcmp(str, "Fim\n") == 0)
                break;
            par = atoi(strtok(str, ";"));
            ord = atoi(strtok(NULL, ";"));
            msg = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            printf("Par = %d/Ordem = %d/Mensagem=%s\n", par, ord, msg);                 

        }
    }
}
```

Test run:

```
> ./lote <lote-input.txt
Par = 3/Ordem = 2/Mensagem=Estou fazendo agora
Par = 0/Ordem = 1/Mensagem=Olá, tudo bem com você?
Par = 1/Ordem = 2/Mensagem=Não
Par = 1/Ordem = 1/Mensagem=Você vem jantar hoje?
Par = 0/Ordem = 2/Mensagem=Tudo sim e você?
Par = 1/Ordem = 3/Mensagem=Vou ter que trabalhar até mais tarde
Par = 2/Ordem = 4/Mensagem=se você lembrar
Par = 3/Ordem = 1/Mensagem=Conseguiu fazer o TP?
Par = 3/Ordem = 3/Mensagem=Esta muito fácil
Par = 2/Ordem = 2/Mensagem=Vou
Par = 2/Ordem = 3/Mensagem=leva na aula amanha
Par = 0/Ordem = 3/Mensagem=Tudo bem tbm
Par = 4/Ordem = 2/Mensagem=Parabéns! Que dia vamos comemorar?
Par = 2/Ordem = 1/Mensagem=Vai precisar da grana?
Par = 4/Ordem = 1/Mensagem=Passei no vestibular!
Par = 3/Ordem = 4/Mensagem=Esta mesmo
```

Just adding: this code **heavily** relies on *well-formed* input. For production quality code, always assume you could get fed garbage (so, for example, `while(1)` might be a bad idea, at least if you don't have a `break` for *error detected*)

Comment: I've tried your code, just as you 've sent me, and it worked with the input reading, but it entered again in an endless loop.

Comment: Could it be your `input.txt` doesn't have a newline after the `-1` at the end? These are the minor pitfalls ... haha --- edit: for writing really *stable* parsers, you *have* to consider any corner case.

Comment: Just for an idea what this could mean for reliable parsing in *pure* C, see what I [came up with for parsing a config file](https://github.com/Zirias/llad/blob/master/src/config.c) ... if it gets to complicated, there are helpers like `yacc`, `flex`, etc ...

Comment: For some reason, the program started to run perfectly with no line add in the .c I've just added an "enter" (\n) into the input.txt and it worked well. This sounds very strange, but anyway, it worked. Thanks to all those who helped me :D

Comment: It's not that strange ... you have these `while(1)` and only check for `"-1\n"` to get out of your loop. If your last line doesn't have a `\n`, you will never exit your loop.